# Radius of convergence formula help

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

[image: In the first example they made 'aj' as j^2 but in the second 1/j^2 as 'aj' yet its practixaly the same function just the j in the second case has been squared]

Also can someone help me differentiate when to use the radius of convergence formula aj/aj+1 from aj+1/aj ? How would i know which one to use in which case? Thanks

Comment: The formula with the limit of $a_j/a_{j+1}$ is applied in both cases.

Comment: Think about the ratio  $\frac {a_n x^n} {a_{n+1}x^{n+1}}$ or   $\frac{a_{n+1}x^{n+1}} {a_n x^n} $

Comment: The Cauchy-Hadamard radius formula: Let $1/R=\lim_{m\to \infty}\sup_{n>m}|a_n|^{1/n}$  in the extended non-negative  reals [0,\infty]. Then $\sum_na_nx^n$ converges when $|x|<R$ and diverges when $|x|>R.$...... In particular, if $\lim_{n\to \infty} |a_n|^{1/n}$ exists in the extended reals then the limit is $1/R.$